# accesskey (HTML attribute) does not work with Microsoft Edge Browser

Tags: html

I am working with Html accesskey attribute for shortcut key

but Microsoft Edge browser does not support it

What is the Microsoft's Edge browser accesskey modifier ?

Thanx in advance

Answer (score 0):

The key modifier to use `accesskey` in Edge is `Alt`.

Other [browsers are tracked at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/accesskey).

Without knowing your use, whether it is for accessibility purposes, if you have to support international audiences, etc., I recommend brushing up on some caveats and best practices in this article from WebAIM: http://webaim.org/techniques/keyboard/accesskey